# Python Image Processing by scikit image and Numpy

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm new to python. I wanna create a program that takes a coloured image, then converts the image from grb to xyz, I mean it converts the coloured values of grb channel to integers and then filter the integers by intensity of color and then regenerate a black and white image where the intense colours are black and rest is white. Is this how I converts the grb values?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open("/home/suzon/Downloads/black.jpg")
print(list(np.asarray(im)))
```

Comment: first convert your rgb image to grayscale using formula `gray = 0.21 * R + 0.72 * G + 0.07 * B`  then you have to do thresholding in order to convert your image into black & white.

Comment: Please show an input image and the expected result.